# DuckDB connecting to OCI bucket

Tags: python, bucket, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, duckdb

can i connect and read files from OCI bucket using duckdb? i have tried to follow their documentation but i'm not sure if OCI is supported.

```
import duckdb
cursor = duckdb.connect()
cursor.execute("INSTALL httpfs;")
cursor.execute("LOAD httpfs;")
cursor.execute(f"SET s3_endpoint='{ENDPOINT}'")
cursor.execute(f"SET s3_region='{region_name}'")
cursor.execute(f"SET s3_access_key_id='{ACCESS_KEY}'")

cursor.execute(f"SET s3_secret_access_key='{SECRET_KEY}'")
cursor.execute("PRAGMA enable_profiling;")

s3_path = https://<your_bucket_namespace>.compat.objectstorage.<your_region>.oraclecloud.com/<your_bucket_name>/<file_path>

t = "SELECT count(*) FROM read_parquet('{s3_path}"
```

i keep getting this error: Error: Invalid Error: Unable to connect to URL

Answer (score 0):

OCI buckets offer an [S3 compatibility API](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Object/Tasks/s3compatibleapi.htm), so DuckDB should be able to read from them.

Try the following steps:

1. Set the `s3_endpoint` to `<your_bucket_namespace>.compat.objectstorage.<your_region>.oraclecloud.com`
2. Set the `s3_url_style` to `path`
3. Then, try reading from `s3://<your_bucket_name>/<file_path>`